# Java Script Variable Problems

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to null out all variables or delete any data inside them. Beside writing

```
Variable1=null;Variable2=null;
```

...so on and so forth. Please no software.

It's not that it's taking much memory, I just want it to load fast. Why I want to `null` the variable is because I want no mistakes even possible. The code looks like this:

```
var First_variable;
for (var I_am_a_loop=0;I_am_a_loop<10;--I_am_a_loop){
    First_variable=prompt("What is your name.");
}
```

Now this is the just but it will have arrays and be more advanced. Why I want to null the variable is because I want no mistakes. I don't have the script complete so I cant give you a whole example.

Comment: What is the specific problem you have? Is the website taking too much memory? Do you have any evidence that these variables are hurting performance somehow? Please provide more details

Comment: If you can show some of your current code we can offer suggestions on how to clean it up.  However without any code to work with our proposed solutions may not apply to your situation.

Comment: Take a look at this guide: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Also please cut lines more often using a dot. I had to read it 3 times before I did even understand what I was reading.

Comment: @user3413190 - sounds a bit like premature optimization. I've added Knuth's famous quote on this subject to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are reassigning the variables in the loop setting them to `null` for a few milliseconds isn't really going to solve any problems for you.

Even if you do declare them within the loop*, modern JavaScript garbage collectors shouldn't have any trouble getting rid of unreferenced variables. The only time you would expect there to be a problem here is with circular references (so the variables always have a reference) or very fast creation of lots of large objects, which causes a lot of garbage handling.

- if you use `var` they are hoisted to the top of the function, if you use `let` they will have block scope (ECMAScript 6 only).

Regarding your comment:

> its not that its taking much memory it is that i want it to make sure it will not mess up it anyway

May I be the first to quote the Donald Knuth...

> Programmers waste enormous amounts of time thinking about, or worrying about, the speed of noncritical parts of their programs, and these attempts at efficiency actually have a strong negative impact when debugging and maintenance are considered. We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%.

I recommend you measure and take no action until you have a measurement that demands it. Write your code to be readable, not efficient, by default.

## Code

Based on the code you added, I'd make some observations... you seem to be decrementing the loop variable, so it is going to prompt forever. You *can* do that if you want, but it is easier to just use a `while(true) {}` loop to make it clear you want to do it.

Otherwise, if you really intend to do the loop 10 times, increment the loop variable instead.

```
var First_variable;
for (var I_am_a_loop = 0; I_am_a_loop < 10; I_am_a_loop++) {
    First_variable=prompt("What is your name.");
}
```

Even if the user enters nothing, the value of `First_variable` will be overwritten. You can always supply a default for when they don't enter a value:

```
var First_variable;
for (var I_am_a_loop = 0; I_am_a_loop < 10; I_am_a_loop++) {
    First_variable = prompt("What is your name.") || 'Default Name';

    alert(First_variable);
}
```

Comment: When did Javascript start having block scope? (Rhetorical question)

Comment: ES6, with the `let` keyword.

Comment: I rarely assume ES6/Harmony unless people have specified it, but fair point.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an odd question, but to answer. You could wrap the relevant code in a function and rely on javascript's function-level scoping to give you fresh instances with each call of the function.

You might be able to refactor your code such that you are using an object or an array in lieu of direct variables.

You could somewhat shorten your example code by one chained assignment statement, such as:

```
variable1 = variable2 = null; // saves you a bunch of '=null;' if nothing else
```

My general thoughts are that if you have fewer than 10 variables you need to reset, it's a minor complaint. If it is many more than 10 variables you need to reset, you probably want to look at your code.